# Error with \IEEEeqnarraymulticol

Tags: ieeetran

I am trying to format a long equation with an overly long LHS, namely:

```
\hat{N}_{A1}(c_A + \hat{N}_{A1})^2 + \hat{N}_{A1}^2a_A(c_A + \hat{N}_{A1})^2 + \hat{N}_{A1}^2b_A(c_A + \hat{N}_{A1}) & = & \hat{N}_{A1}a_B^2a_A^2c_A(c_A + \hat{N}_{A1})^2
```

I tried to use the \IEEEeqnarraymulticol command with 3 columns merged into one, left justified like this:

```
\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rCl}
\IEEEeqnarraymulticol{3}{1}{
\hat{N}_{A1}(c_A + \hat{N}_{A1})^2 + \hat{N}_{A1}^2a_A(c_A + \hat{N}_{A1})^2 + \hat{N}_{A1}^2b_A(c_A + \hat{N}_{A1})
}\\ \quad & = & \hat{N}_{A1}a_B^2a_A^2c_A(c_A + \hat{N}_{A1})^2
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}
```

But I get the error:

> "Class IEEEtran Error: Invalid column type "1" in  in \IEEEeqnarraymulticol.

Any suggestions on how to make IEEEtranstools recognize this column type?  FYI, it doesn't work with column type "2" or "3"...

Comment: You should have `l` ("ell") and not `1` (one) in the second argument to `\IEEEeqnarraymulticol`